# CTRL + Shift + V doesn’t work properly (Frame Animation)

Tags: animation

I have a problem with my animation. When I try to copy and reverse a frame, it doesn’t work properly… If I just copy it, it works 100%, so the command CTRL + V works. The problem is just when I do CTRL + Shift + V…
I tried different suggestions that I’ve found, for example to reset the rotation and position of all the bones…
I really don’t know why it doesn’t work.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks

here you can find my blender file (https://easyupload.io/yr32vp)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130343/discussion-on-question-by-raffaele-de-luca-ctrl-shift-v-doesnt-work-properl).

Comment: please share your current file (with the keyframes you've created)

Comment: I think I ve found the problem: the problem was that at the frame0 I created just the keyframe of the bone "mano001.L" (Left side) but I didn't create the keyframe of the relative bone on the right side XD

Comment: I've now solved the problem with the shoulders and hands, but still the feet are not perfect... here is the file https://easyupload.io/bbpgks

Comment: SOLVED the problem with the feet too! There wasn't the same "rotation x" between the right and the relative left side of a bone of the foot https://streamable.com/uc0pug

Answer (score 0):

maybe:
goto preferences/keymap/key-bindings
enter "ctrl shift v" in the search field

look wether there is any other command assigned to the same keys - note: key bindings depend on the blender space/region/window (actually used by you) .